# PHP Merge array by same index

Tags: php, laravel

I have two arrays by array_merge() that look like this:

```
 Array(
            [1] => Array(
                  [date] => 2018-09-25
                  [size_one] => 'XL'
                  [name_one] => 'Shoes'
                )
            [2] => Array(
                    [date] => 2018-09-25
                    [size_two] => 'L'
                    [name_two] => 'Shirt'
                )
            [3] => Array(
                    [date] => 2018-09-26
                    [size_two] => 'L'
                    [name_two] => 'Shirt'
                )
            )
```

If same date value, I need as a result something like the following:

```
Array(
                [1] => Array(
                      [date] => 2018-09-25
                      [size_one] => 'XL'
                      [name_one] => 'Shoes'
                      [size_two] => 'L'
                      [name_two] => 'Shirt'
                    )
                [2] => Array(
                        [date] => 2018-09-26
                        [size_two] => 'L'
                        [name_two] => 'Shirt'
                    )
                )
```

want to be able to put these into an array for laravel,  Can someone show me the proper way to merge these arrays?

Comment: You can use laravel collection. First you need to group by date, then merge each group and remove the keys.
`$result = collect($input)
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->map(function ($item) {
            return array_merge(...$item->toArray());
        })
        ->values();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) functions, with some basic `foreach` looping and conditionals, you can try the following (steps explained in the code comments):

```
// $input is your input array

// initialize output array
$output = array();

// loop over the input
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {

    // check if the date key is already set in the output or not
    if ( array_key_exists($value['date'], $output) ) {

        // this is duplicate based on date - merge into output
        $output[$value['date']] = array_merge($output[$value['date']], 
                                              $value);
    } else {

        // new entry for date
        $output[$value['date']] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's Work.. thanks.

Comment: @gilangtaufik happy to help :)